# Не отображается реклама на реальном устройстве

Tags: java, admob, реклама

Всем привет. я добавил в свое приложение межстраничную рекламу с Admob,при запуска и тестировании на эмуляторе все работает корректно,отображается тестовая реклама,но при тесте на реальном устройстве рекламы нет. В чем может быть дело? подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Вбиваете в Гугле get started admob и переходите по второй ссылке. И с самого начала по вкладкам идёте, все понятно и с видеоинструкциями.

Comment: И вы должны в своем приложении указать id приложения и id рекламного блока, которые вы получите после добавления приложения в аккаунте admob

Answer (score 1):

этому есть куча причин.

1. У адмоба для твоего ИП адреса закончилась реклама, попробуй с мобильного интернета или с вай фая соседа.
2. Устаревший андроид сдк
3. Может быть не правильно реализована
4. Если в функции вызова рекламы тест девайс ид, снеси и попробуй реальные объявления.
   Желательно посмотри видео "как встроить рекламу admob" ( канал Android Helper)
   У меня были случаи когда реклама не показывалась, причины 1,2.
   Удачи!